# How can I stop receiving the results of this calculations?

Tags: xlop

I use `xlop` \usepackage to prepare for my son. Now I don't want to show the resuls of this calculations. How can I do it?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{color,xlop}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
Calculate the problems
 \begin{multicols}{4}
  \opadd[carryadd=false]{28}{11}\\
  \opadd[carryadd=false]{12}{34}\\
  \opadd[carryadd=false]{13}{42}\\
  \opadd[carryadd=false]{25}{20}\\
  \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\newcommand{\white}[1]{}


  \opadd[carryadd=false,resultstyle=\white]{28}{11}\\
```